# Aggregate heating energy demand based on building data and street segments with PostgreSQL and PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, aggregate

I have two datasets / tables:

1. Georeferenced building data with the yearly heating energy demand per building
2. Street line segments from OpenStreetMap.

My goal is to calculate the total heating energy demand per street line segment (energy demand per meter of street).

Is there a (ideally performant) way to do the following calculations in SQL?

```
for every street segment calculate the heating density as follows:
  find all buildings that are closest to this segment:
    sum up the heating energy demand of the matching buildings and divide it by the length of the street segment
```

So far I could not figure out how to translate the above pseudocode into a SQL query. My dataset contains about 40k buildings and 30k street segments.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which explains how our Focused question/Best answer model operates. Please [Edit] the question to include your attempt at SQL and remove the ArcPy option (second question).

Comment: If you search for *join by closest postgis* you will find many examples on how to get started, for example: https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/knn.html